# PHP SUM object values

Tags: php

When I try `print_r( $category->child() )`I got this: (pastebin: https://pastebin.com/hSnfMpLH)

```
Array ( [2] => IPS\forums\Forum Object ( [_url:protected] => [_childrenResults:protected] => Array ( [44ecbc64e2a074fc12588cf2dbcb2596] => Array ( ) ) [_permissions:protected] => Array ( [perm_id] => 2 [perm_view] => * [perm_2] => * [perm_3] => 3,4,6 [perm_4] => 3,4,6 [perm_5] => 3,4,6 [perm_6] => [perm_7] => ) [_originalPermissions:protected] => Array ( [perm_id] => 2 [perm_view] => * [perm_2] => * [perm_3] => 3,4,6 [perm_4] => 3,4,6 [perm_5] => 3,4,6 [perm_6] => [perm_7] => ) [noCopyButton] => [contentPostedIn:protected] => Array ( ) [_followData] => [queued:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [topics] => 1 [posts] => 1490710 [last_post] => 1490714195 [last_poster_id] => 1 [last_poster_name] => Evaldas [position] => 1 [password] => [password_override] => [last_title] => Welcome! [last_id] => 1 [sort_key] => last_post [show_rules] => 0 [preview_posts] => 0 [allow_poll] => 1 [inc_postcount] => 1 [skin_id] => 0 [parent_id] => 1 [redirect_url] => [redirect_on] => 0 [redirect_hits] => 0 [sub_can_post] => 1 [permission_showtopic] => 0 [queued_topics] => 0 [queued_posts] => 0 [forum_allow_rating] => 0 [min_posts_post] => 0 [min_posts_view] => 0 [can_view_others] => 1 [name_seo] => a-test-forum [seo_last_title] => welcome [seo_last_name] => dewagg [last_x_topic_ids] => [forums_bitoptions] => 0 [disable_sharelinks] => 0 [tag_predefined] => [archived_topics] => 0 [archived_posts] => 0 [ipseo_priority] => -1 [viglink] => 1 [qa_rate_questions] => * [qa_rate_answers] => * [icon] => [category_id] => 1 [app] => forums [perm_type] => forum [perm_type_id] => 2 [owner_only] => 0 [friend_only] => 0 [authorized_users] => ) [_new:protected] => [changed] => Array ( ) [skipCloneDuplication] => ) [8] => IPS\forums\Forum Object ( [_url:protected] => [_childrenResults:protected] => Array ( [44ecbc64e2a074fc12588cf2dbcb2596] => Array ( ) ) [_permissions:protected] => Array ( [perm_id] => 50 [perm_view] => * [perm_2] => * [perm_3] => 4,3,6 [perm_4] => 4,3,6 [perm_5] => 4,3,6 [perm_6] => [perm_7] => ) [_originalPermissions:protected] => Array ( [perm_id] => 50 [perm_view] => * [perm_2] => * [perm_3] => 4,3,6 [perm_4] => 4,3,6 [perm_5] => 4,3,6 [perm_6] => [perm_7] => ) [noCopyButton] => [contentPostedIn:protected] => Array ( ) [_followData] => [queued:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 8 [topics] => 2 [posts] => 2 [last_post] => 1490712622 [last_poster_id] => 1 [last_poster_name] => Evaldas [position] => 7 [password] => [password_override] => [last_title] => hahahahah [last_id] => 4 [sort_key] => last_post [show_rules] => 0 [preview_posts] => 0 [allow_poll] => 1 [inc_postcount] => 1 [skin_id] => [parent_id] => 1 [redirect_url] => [redirect_on] => 0 [redirect_hits] => 0 [sub_can_post] => 1 [permission_showtopic] => 0 [queued_topics] => 0 [queued_posts] => 0 [forum_allow_rating] => 0 [min_posts_post] => 0 [min_posts_view] => 0 [can_view_others] => 1 [name_seo] => test-forum [seo_last_title] => hahahahah [seo_last_name] => dewagg [last_x_topic_ids] => [forums_bitoptions] => 8 [disable_sharelinks] => 0 [tag_predefined] => [archived_topics] => 0 [archived_posts] => 0 [ipseo_priority] => -1 [viglink] => 1 [qa_rate_questions] => * [qa_rate_answers] => * [icon] => [category_id] => 1 [app] => forums [perm_type] => forum [perm_type_id] => 8 [owner_only] => 0 [friend_only] => 0 [authorized_users] => ) [_new:protected] => [changed] => Array ( ) [skipCloneDuplication] => ) ) 1
```

How can I sum all **topics**? I've tried: `array_sum( $category->child()['topics'] )` etc, but It not works. Sorry for my bad english

P.S found on stackoverflow:

> Or as suggested by @MarkBaker:
>
> $sum = array_sum((array)$myobj);

But how can I select 'topics' ?

`var_dump` https://pastebin.com/EqJ5TPuA

---

New code:

```
public function countingTotalTopics()
{
    foreach( $this->children() as $child )
    {
        $return = $child->topics;
    }
    
    return $return;
}
```

And when I try `$category->countingTotalTopics()` it gives me topics only from first child, how can I get it from another? I think I should call `$child->countingTotalTopics()` again in foreach, but how?

Comment: Instead of `print_r` output, provide `var_dump` output.

Comment: And if you can, put `<pre>` around it before you print/dump, this is kind of messy to read.

Comment: @trincot ok, updated

Comment: Try using: echo "<pre>".print_r( $category->child(),true )."</pre>". It may offer a better view of the structure.

Comment: Your variable is of a certain class. You should use the methods available in that class to get information. Do you have the definition of the class, or are you using a library for this topic management? If so, which?

Comment: It seams `topics` data are protected! The object is for what class?

Comment: I don't know, I'm developing IPS4 script

Comment: Without knowing the class of this object, there is little we can do. Check the documentation of whatever library you are using.

Comment: wait pls @trincot, I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently getting only the *last* child's topics. Use this `array_merge`-based function instead:

```
public function countingTotalTopics() {
    $return = [];
    foreach( $this->children() as $child ) {
        $return = array_merge($return, (array) $child->topics);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I've changed from `$return = $child->topics` to `$return = $return + $child->topics` and now everything works fine, is it good solution?

Comment: There is a small difference between `+` and `array_merge`: if the `topics` arrays have numerical, sequential keys, then `+` will not produce the desired result, but in all other cases it behaves the same way as `array_merge`. Maybe for `array_merge` to work in your case you need to cast it explicitly to `array`. See update. But if `+` works fine, then go with it.